# WPF ListView Highlight Color don't change

Tags: wpf, xaml, listview, highlight, listviewitem

I have a ListView with three TextBlock for each Item.
The first one has the default color (black) and the others has the property Foreground set to gray.

When I select an item the color of the first TextBlock becomes blue but the others stay gray and are hard to read.

I want that all the text become white color when the item is selected.
How I do that ?

Edit :
My style :

```
 <UserControl.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Resources>
```

My ListView

```
        <ListView  x:Name="lvResultat"  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Background="{x:Null}"  
                      Margin="4"                       
                      HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                           ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                      ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                      IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"    

                      ItemsSource="{Binding ResultatsRecherche}" SelectedItem="{Binding ResultatSelectione, Mode=TwoWay}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" MouseDoubleClick="lvResultat_MouseLeftDoubleClick" >
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="viewModel:ResultatRechercheViewModel">
                <Grid Height="86" Margin="2"  >
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="1.5*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="0.5*"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Titre}" 
                                       FontSize="20" FontWeight="Bold"  />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding SousTitre}" Grid.Row="1" 
                                       FontStyle="Italic" Foreground="Gray"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Resume}" Grid.Row="2"  TextTrimming="WordEllipsis"
                                        Foreground="Gray"/>

                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

I also tried things like

```
<Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
    <Style.Resources>
        <!--<SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="White" />-->
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}" Color="White" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="White" />
    </Style.Resources>
</Style>
```

EDIT 2 : 
I have discovered that the custom style changes the color of Textblock which have the default property as Foreground (black).
If I specife Black for the color of the text of the first textblock, the text doesn't change anymore of color when the item is selected.

Picture :
[image]

Comment: Please show your XAML so we can see what you mean by `I have a ListView with two TextBlock in it`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could achieve what you are trying to do by converting your code from having `DataTemplate` for a `ListViewItem` to having a `ControlTemplate`

This is what I tried:

ListViewItem Style:

```
<Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                <Border x:Name="ContentBorder"
                                Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                Margin="4">
                    <Grid Height="86" Margin="2"  >
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="1.5*"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="0.5*"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Titre}" 
                               FontSize="20" FontWeight="Bold"  />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding SousTitre}" Grid.Row="1" Name="st"
                               FontStyle="Italic" Foreground="Gray"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Resume}" Grid.Row="2"  TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" Name="r"
                                Foreground="Gray"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" TargetName="st" Value="White" />
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" TargetName="r" Value="White" />
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="ContentBorder"  Value="DeepSkyBlue" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

and then I removed DataTemplate from the `ListView` XAML:

```
<ListView  x:Name="lvResultat"  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Background="{x:Null}"  
           Margin="4"                       
           HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
           ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
           ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
           IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"    
           ItemsSource="{Binding ResultatsRecherche}" SelectedItem="{Binding ResultatSelectione, Mode=TwoWay}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" >
</ListView>
```

However, if you must use `DateTemplate`, then what you could do is have a property called `IsSelected` on your `ViewModel`, `ResultatRechercheViewModel` and then have DataTriggers on that property in your `DataTemplate`.

Updated DataTemplate:

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="viewModel:ResultatRechercheViewModel">
        <Grid Height="86" Margin="2"  >
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="1.5*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="0.5*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Titre}" 
                           FontSize="20" FontWeight="Bold"  />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding SousTitre}" Grid.Row="1"  Name="st"
                           FontStyle="Italic" Foreground="Gray"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Resume}" Grid.Row="2"  TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" Name="r"
                            Foreground="Gray"/>

        </Grid>
        <DataTemplate.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" TargetName="st" Value="White" />
                <Setter Property="Foreground" TargetName="r" Value="White" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </DataTemplate.Triggers>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

And, you need to update your `ViewModel` code to set `IsSelected` property, Below is code from my MainViewModel:

```
public ResultatRechercheViewModel ResultatSelectione
{
    get { return _resultatSelectione; }
    set
    {
        if (_resultatSelectione != null)
        {
            _resultatSelectione.IsSelected = false;
        }

        _resultatSelectione = value;

        _resultatSelectione.IsSelected = true;
    }
}
```

Hope this resolves your problem or gives you some ideas to resolve your problem.

Answer (score 3):

Try this syntax

```
<ListView>
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                     <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    ...
</ListView>
```

Comment: The colors of the two "grey" textblocks doesn't change -_-

Comment: The stated questions is: I want that all the text become white color when the item is selected How I do that ?"  Did it fix that or not?

Comment: No : The text of the first become white. The texts of the others stay grey.

Comment: I watend to say "of the first TextBlock in my ItemTempalte". I have added a picture for better understanding (thanks for helping me)

Comment: Next time start with a clear problem statement.  Maybe that hard coded Foreground="Gray" is a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Foreground Try use style for listView items:

```
 <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
      <Style.Triggers>
           <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
           </Trigger>
       </Style.Triggers>
 </Style>
```

Comment: How does this changes the **TextBlock**'s foregound?

Comment: It should change Foreground for all items, doesn't matter what kind date template you use. I had same issue, and my listview contain 6 textbox, this style helped me.