# Change the color of ListViewItem Content when Item is selected

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview

I want to invert the color (`Fill`) of a `FrameworkElement` in a `ListViewItem`  when the `ListViewItem` is selected.

Problematic is that the `FrameworkElement` that should have the selected Color is in another `DataTemplate` in a nested `DataTemplateSelector`.

Example:

```
         <ListView>
            <ListViewItem>
                <ContentPresenter>
                    <ContentPresenter.ContentTemplateSelector>
                        <selector:IconTypeSelector>
                            <selector:IconTypeSelector.SuperImportantIcon>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Rectangle Width="27"
                                           Height="27"
                                           Fill="{DynamicResource ColorThatShouldChange}"><!--This is what i want to have the font color of my ListViewElements  -->
                                    </Rectangle>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </selector:IconTypeSelector.SuperImportantIcon>
                        </selector:IconTypeSelector>
                    </ContentPresenter.ContentTemplateSelector>
                </ContentPresenter>
            </ListViewItem>
        </ListView>
```

Best case scenario would be:
My `FrameworkElement` (`Rectangle` in example) binds on the same color as the font color of text in a `ListViewItem`which gets inverted when selected.

Comment: Could you bind the Rectangle's fill to the template's background/fill data? This may save some headache. You could then just change the background on an event of "OnSelected" (or whatever the event actually is). Put this as a comment as not quite sure if this will work.

Answer (score 0):

Read [How to set a WPF ListView Selected Item color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14838524/how-to-set-a-wpf-listview-selected-item-color) and [WPF ListView Highlight Color don't change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19766317/wpf-listview-highlight-color-dont-change)

All you have to do is Bind your color to Bordes's BackGround.

Answer (score -2):

you must be having the index number of the selected Item. on the Backend Code. Find the index and set System.Drawing,Color Of your Choice.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < list.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        if (list.Items[i].Bounds.Contains(e.Location) == true)
        {
            list.Items[i].BackColor = Color.Blue; // highlighted item
        }
        else
        {
            list.Items[i].BackColor = SystemColors.Window; // normal item
        }
    }
```

Comment: Something Like this:

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < list.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            if (list.Items[i].Bounds.Contains(e.Location) == true)
            {
                list.Items[i].BackColor = Color.Blue; // highlighted item
            }
            else
            {
                list.Items[i].BackColor = SystemColors.Window; // normal item
            }
        }